# Retorno do oci_new_cursor

Tags: php, oracle, pl-sql

Olá!
Possuo a seguinte duvida: a função da oracle para PHP  oci_new_cursor, só pode ser usada quando o cursor já existe no banco?

Por exemplo, eu acabei de criar minha consulta dentro do meu código php:

```
$query2 = "DECLARE
v_consulta NUMBER;
CURSOR cursbv IS
 SELECT proxnumorc FROM pcconsum FOR UPDATE of proxnumorc;
 BEGIN
   OPEN cursbv;
     FETCH cursbv INTO v_consulta;
     UPDATE pcconsum SET proxnumorc = proxnumorc + 1;
     COMMIT;
   CLOSE cursbv;
 END;";


$s2 = oci_parse($c, $query2);

$r2 = oci_execute($s2);
```

---

Posso usar essa função no meu código?
Pois preciso recuperar o valor do select que está dentro do cursor.
obs: Estou usando oracle 11g.
Se alguém souber como funciona e puder me ajudar. Agradeço desde já